# Use Excel VBA command to enable Draw>Pen tool

Tags: excel, vba

I have a drawing that needs to be marked up in Sheet1. Originally, this was done by using a command button which creates a circle Shape. I'd instead like to use the Pen tool under the Draw ribbon to allow customization of the shape. Essentially, I would like a command button that, once pressed, enables the pen feature.

I've already researched forums all around. I've also tried recording a macro but that doesn't work either.

```
 Sub Macro1()
 'My attempt at recording a macro for adding a rentangle.
     ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 407.25, 77.25, 28.5, 27.75). _
    Select
 End Sub

 Sub pen()
 'My attempt at recording a macro which enables the pen feature. Nothing gets recorded.
 ' pen Macro
 '
 End Sub
```

No errors, just no drawing pen enabled/selected.

Comment: Nothing was recorded, because nothing actually happened - this is similar to changing the border width or color without actually drawing any borders, or toggling bold or italic without actually typing anything anywhere: as far as the worksheet is concerned, nothing happened. Your best bet is probably to locate the command you want to execute (you'll have to find it in `Application.CommandBars`), and execute it - if the command isn't in any `CommandBar`, your only shot might be to use `Application.SendKeys` to send the hotkey for the command you want to run.

Comment: ...where is that *pen tool* command, exactly?

Comment: The pen tool(s) is located under the Draw ribbon. You have to add-in the Draw ribbon in similar fashion to adding in the Developer Ribbon.

Comment: As far As i know the recorder does not record this

Comment: I have all Ribbon tabs shown, none of them is "Draw", and the only thing I can find that remotely resembles "pen" is "Pens", under "Ink Tools", which would be a contextual Ribbon tab only shown when the current `Selection` makes sense for it. What version are you using?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: That is available in 356 / off 2019 :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout gah, I should have known, I have it at home... anyway I'd try to locate the `CommandBarButton` for it if it exists, and run its `Execute` method once found. Failing that, `SendKeys` seems the only remaining option.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: I was thinking the same LOL. Unfortunately I do not have 2016 (365 Pro) or 2019 at the moment...